# How can a List<Long> references to an ArrayList which has BigInteger values

Tags: java, spring-boot, casting, spring-data, generic-collections

This method is defined in a JpaRepository and runs a native PostgreSQL query.

```
List<Long> distributorIds = distributorRepository
.findDistributorIdsWithChildren(distributorId)
```

It runs with no exception and **on runtime I see BigInteger values in returned distributorIds ArrayList instead of Long values**.

It's same with this question: [Bug in Spring Data JPA: Spring Data returns List<BigInteger> instead of List<Long>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31011797/bug-in-spring-data-jpa-spring-data-returns-listbiginteger-instead-of-listlon)

So how can this bug occur? I mean **how JAVA allows this**? If Java doesn't check this kind of type errors isn't it a problem with generics in JAVA.

Note: I also checked the type hierarchy for Long and BigInteger and there is no sub/super class relation.

Comment: Generic type checks are a compile time feature. At runtime all type information is lost. See "type erasure". The behavior above can easily happen if, for example, a legacy API that uses non-generic collections is mapped to an API that uses generics and requires a cast of the collection.

Comment: Please write this as an answer to allow me to accept it.. Thank you! I don't remember since when I didn't see a non-typed ArrayList, that's why I couldn't think about CAST issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic type checks are a compile time feature. At runtime all type information is lost. See "type erasure". The behavior you see can easily happen if, for example, a legacy API that uses non-generic collections is mapped to an API that uses generics and requires a cast of the collection. If that collection happens to contain objects of an unexpected type you will, sadly, only find out at runtime.